# how to show local push notification (on app icon on home screen like i-phone) in android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, badge, localnotification

I am given a task to show local push notification. I have successfully completed showing push notification on bar. But also I have to show local notification on app launching icon on home screen like in i-phone. See the image [image]

I want this kind of notification. Here, may be the dialog I create using custom AlertDialog. But I'm stuck with the notification on the app icon i.e. that bubble containing notification no on upper right corner of app icon. I think this functionality is not given by android sdk. but our client says that she has seen these kinds of notifications on her Android mobile for some applications.
 So is it possible in Android, and if yes then how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a "badge" and I'm sorry to tell you that this does not exist on Android - your client must be mistaken.

One workaround you could do is to create a widget for your app (and you can even make it look like an app icon if you wish...), and you can add a badge or update how it looks any way you choose.

Comment: yes, I read everywhere on net about this, and everywhere it is mentioned about that widget, but I it looks quite hard to do. By the way thanks for your answer

Comment: don't get discouraged - it's really not too hard, particularly if it's a simple widget. plenty of code out there you can copy/paste and adjust.

Comment: Those badges are possible for system apps in the Samsung custom launcher in some Samsung devices, for example the Galaxy SII. But those Apps are using a Samsung only API that can not be used by not Samsung Developers. Only to clarify why somebody might think that this is possible in Android.

Comment: true. you could *just* write your own launcher! hah